# How can I check if MediaPlayer has finished loading a sound?

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

I am trying to play multiple sounds at the same time for a simple game using the MediaPlayer class (`System.Windows.Media.Mediaplayer`).

To play the same sound multiple times at the same time, I created my own class, which loads the same sound many times.

Here is a short example:

```
sound = new MediaPlayer[count]; //array of MediaPlayers

//...

for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
{
      sound[a] = new MediaPlayer();
      sound[a].Open(new System.Uri(sp + pfad)); //load sound
}
```

Here is my problem:
If I try to play a sound shortly after starting the game either I can't hear the sound or the beginning of the first sound I loaded will start playing (even if I tried to play a completely different sound).

It seems like all these MediaPlayers (I'm loading ~100) need some time to load the sounds.
Therefore I'm looking for a way to check if the loading is done.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Loading or playback? When the media has finished playback it rises the MediaEnded event, when buffering has finished it rises BufferingEnded event. [MediaPlayer events.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer_events%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It looks like that the MediaOpened event is what i need. Testing it now.

Comment: If I not mistaking, the media player buffers the data before opening, that's why you may use BufferingEnded event.

Comment: The BufferingEnded event never appears in my code. (I tested it with a MessageBox within the eventhandler, the MessageBox never poped up.) here is my code http://pastebin.com/m41YKhMC

Comment: I have doubts about this line: `sound[a] = new MediaPlayer();` in cycle. At first you declare array of MediaPlayer and beyond you declare each element of array again as MediaPlayer.

Comment: The first declaration declares an array wich is able to hold objects of the class Mediaplayer, but the array is still empty. Therefore I fill it with objects of the class MediaPlayer in a loop. If I doesn't do this each element of the array would be null. Or did you mean something else ?